# How to do Java polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

***Edit: should be a2 = new B()***
I don't understand why the result for a2.foo(b) is 3 in the following practice question.

I thought with polymorphism, the dynamic types method would run with the method signature that takes the argument that corresponds with the static type.

```
public class A {
    public int foo(Object o) {
        System.out.println(1);
        return 1;
    }

    public int foo(A a) {
        System.out.println(2);
        return 2;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public int foo(A a) {
        System.out.println(3);
        return 3;
    }

    public int foo(B b) {
        System.out.println(4);
        return 4;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a2 = new B();
        B b = new B();
        a2.foo(b);
    }
}
```

The answer my school has given is a2.foo(b) returns 3, however I thought it would return 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually it would return 2. Perhaps you had an error copying the question, and `A a2 = new A();` should be `A a2 = new B();`?

Comment: I've just run your code and actually that returns `2`, not `3`.

Comment: hey, sorry, a2 is actually B()

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317294/i-was-given-a-good-answer-but-then-noticed-that-the-question-is-wrong-what-sh

Comment: You already got answers on your question, by manipulating it you invalidated all existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. Overloading
2. Overriding

*Overloading* is about having two different methods in the same class with the same name but different argument types (so they are different). *Overriding* and polymorphism is about having the same single method in two different classes.

Classes `A` and `B` both *overload* the `foo` method: they have two methods with the same name. In `A` one method takes `Object` as a parameter and one takes `A` as a parameter. In `B` one takes `A` as a parameter and one takes `B`. Of these four methods, two are the same (`foo(A)`).

The `foo(A)` method in `B` overrides the `foo(A)` method in `A`. The `foo(B)` method however is a different method.

So when you call `a2.foo(b)` you are calling the `foo(A)` method. It must be, as  `a2` is declared as `A` and `A` doesn't have a `A.foo(B)`. Since `a2` is an actually an object of type `B`, you are calling `B.foo(A)` as it overrides `A.foo(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As the question was changed, the answer is now `3` as `A.foo(A)` is called but overridden.

---

If `a2` was a `B` then the overridden method would be used, never an overloaded method.

But `a2` is an `A` and which class only has one method `foo(A)` which can be called, so it prints `2`

In short, only the type of `this` on the left hand side of `.` will change the choice of method called.

Comment: Worth noting that it returns `2`, not `3`.

Comment: @Amongalen agreed, it's wasn't clear the way I wrote it, thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry, a2 is actually B()

Answer (score 0):

`a2` is obviously `A`, therefore `A#foo` is executed. It is possible (compiles and executes) since `B` is instance of `A`.

Since `A#foo` is executed, answer is `2` (not `3` and not `4`).

Comment: Perhaps you need to update this as the question was edited. It is wrong as it stands.